# Accessing Eclipse Che server through desktop Eclipse install?

Tags: eclipse-che

I'm a totally blind developer who is looking at Eclipse Che. While I'm able to create a project the web interface is mostly inaccessible, I can not run an app, view console output, etc. Is there a way to access an Eclipse Che server through a standard desktop install of Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the Eclipse Che workspaces with a desktop editor/IDE. There are instructions on setting that up in the docs: https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/desktop-ide-mounting

Personally I like the mount-and-sync option for times when I don't use the Che browser IDE.